# How to render angularjs content conditional?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to render some ui content in the frontend, based on the `boolean` state of a controller variable.

controller:

```
$scope.test = [
    myvar = true
    //some other variables and data
];
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller"mycontroller">
    <p>'{{test}}'</p>
    <p>'{{test.myvar}}'</p>
    <p ng-if="{{test.myvar}}">show this content</p>
</div>
```

Result:

```
'[true]'
''
```

The 2nd statement is somehow not rendered. Why?

Comment: `$scope.test = {
    myvar : true
    //some other variables and data
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is a literal for arrays, which do not have string keys.
`=` assigns to a variable, it's not used for associating keys and values.

You want an object literal, which looks like this:

```
$scope.test = {
    myvar: true
};
```

You've also messed up the syntax in the directive:

```
<p ng-if="test.myvar">show this content</p>
```

`{{}}` is not necessary in basically all directives; the content of the directive attribute is parsed inside the directive, it does not need to be bound. `{{}}` is pretty much only necessary for "echoing" data.

Comment: Thanks. But still the `ng-if="{{test.myvar}}"` is not shown...

Comment: The syntax there is `ng-if="test.myvar"`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript objects are created with the help of curly braces, like this:

```
$scope.test = {
    myvar: true
};
```

And, when using `ng` directives, angular parses the variable without `{{ }}`, that's why you should just do this:

```
ng-if="test.myvar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Square barckets it's an array. Ex: ['Charles', 'Jay', 'Jonh']
Curly brackets it's an object. Ex: { name: 'Charles', phone: '91332323'}

In a object you can access the variable with "." notation.

You're looking for an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to put curly braces for ng-if ..just use ng-if="test.myvar" and use

```
$scope.test = {
myvar: true  };
```